# Set group of resizable images in center

Tags: html, image, center, resizable

I used of the below code for make four resizable images but i don't know how can i set them in the center of page.
please help me.

```
<img src="..." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
<img src="..." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
<img src="..." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
<img src="..." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
.center
{
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="center">
        <img src="...." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
        <img src="...." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
        <img src="...." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
        <img src="...." style=" max-width: 25%; height: 100%; width: auto; ">
</div>
```